# Did the Welsh ever call Britain Albion?

Tags: britain, celtic, roman-britain

I understand that the word exists in Welsh, but that it's a modern loanword from Gaelic referring to Scotland.

[Albion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Albion) first appears in ancient Greek accounts along with [Ierne](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0064%3Aalphabetic%20letter%3DI%3Aentry%20group%3D3%3Aentry%3Dierne-geo) as being part of the British Isles. 
The Romans don't appear to have used the term much, preferring Britannia though the term survived enough for Aethelstan in the 10th century to use it as [part of his title](http://www.anglo-saxons.net/hwaet/?do=get&type=person&id=Athelstan).
Presumably the word survived in Gaelic or maybe Pictish which is where the modern word comes from, but does anyone know if the word has any historic use in Welsh?

I can hazard a guess that Roman rule replaced the native word in common use, much like Welsh adopted the use of Welsh to refer to themselves instead of the native Cymry, though it's only a guess.

Comment: Perhaps English.Stackexchange.com is a better fit for this. What do others think?

Comment: My question has nothing to do with the English or the English language. While it has a language element to it, I'm primarily interested in the historic use of the word to describe the island of Great Britain in a Celtic context. I'm hoping someone familiar with the Roman or sub-Roman period or someone familiar with Welsh history can answer this.

Comment: The word probably originates in the Common Brythonic language, and so predates Welsh by some margin. From there, the term reached the Greek world no later than the 5th century BC. I've read suggestions that the Latinised form of the word may have brought back with the Romans, and survived here after they left.

Comment: Wikipedia addresses the Brittonic and Welsh forms of it, but not when and how they were used.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens The first uses appear to have been recorded way before english did ever exist, and the OP is asking about Welsh, no English. I think this is better here.

Comment: The regular contributors at *English.stackexchange.com* are much more experienced at researching the etymology of English words than those here. It's just a matter of where the individuals who can best answer this question hang out most.

Comment: Given that the question is about the usage of the word in the _Welsh_ language, I'm not sure that English.stackexchange.com would be the right forum.

Comment: Please outline, with references, how the [etymology of *Albion* from Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Albion#Etymology) fails to answer your question.
@sempaiscuba: Thank you. Corrected link here now.

Comment: Perhaps you would read medieval Welsh literature in Latin and Welsh to find use of "Albion".  The normal Welsh word for Britain was Prydain.  A board about medieval Welsh literature in Latin and Welsh would be  a logical place to ask.

Comment: You maybe need to be clearer by what you mean by "the Welsh" or "in Welsh": Wales wasn't a unified entity in anything like its current borders; Welsh or languages closely related (like Brythonic/Brittonic, Cumbric, and Cornish) were spoken through much of Britain; and the Welsh seem to have preserved (and possibly edited) documents in Cumbric or Brythonic from far beyond Wales.

Answer (score 6):

I believe it's thought to be a hellenisation of the common brythonic form *ėlβɨð [1](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Reconstruction:Proto-Brythonic/%C4%97l%CE%B2%C9%A8%C3%B0) giving *Albíōn* and latinised as *Albiōn*.

That common Brythonic form giving Old Welsh *elbid*, meaning that native word wasn't replaced and continues to the modern day with the Welsh word *elfydd* "earth, world, land, country, district".

The Common-Brythonic meaning is *thought* to be “upper world” (as opposed to underworld) so in the British context it likely wasn't used as a term for the island of Britain *per se* but the world in general; the fact that it comes into Latin and Greek as a word for Britain suggests the Britons they encountered were referring to the island as the "world" and travellers took the word to just mean the island.

I've not found any stringent sources beyond Wiktionary and Wikipedia so take all this with some healthy scepticism. But, if true the **Britons would of used a Brythonic form of the word akin to *ėlβɨð, and by the time any idea of 'Welsh' identity was starting to ferment elbid, and later elfydd**, *unless they were speaking Latin, in which case they might have used Albiōn.*

Answer (score -2):

There was no Wales in Viking times or before hand. Albion related to traders at see who called the white cliffs of Dover the (white) Albion land. Nothing to do with Scotland or Wales. The wild lands of the Pict not Alba as some repeatedly say is correct. Albion relates to Dover cliffs only. First sight of Britainia until the Roman who used Britanus as base. Built a wall across England to stop the Pict mingling with them. Wales as Cymry was also at first linked in with England but blue faced warriors from the hills put up resistance but Rome moved in on them fast and cleared them out .Built CARDIFF after Chester to protect interest and involve Business men from Roman world to trade in Chester all over Britanicus. The Normans took over and Wales as subdued as trouble makers .Scotland was secured owing to location for defensive safety doing away with border so to defend all land from attach. Scotland was part of all same as England but England was warm and they lived there instead. All was once part of France joined up to Britani and so my guess it is why Romans called us Britain

Comment: I've read this a couple of times and it's not at all clear what you're trying to say. This could do with a re-write to put in some structure, some focus on answering the actual question and to add some sources for the assertions you're making.

Comment: Some sources and formatting would greatly help this answer.

Comment: I'm not sure this actually answers the question.